# Maven error while installing Android app - MojoExecution

Tags: android, maven

Im pretty new to Maven and I want to run my Android app from console, but when i type `mvn clean install` I get the following error :

```
    [ERROR] Error when generating sources.org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: 
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:484)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.execute(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:195)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
    Caused by: com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.ExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid && /Users/myName/Desktop/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/aapt package -m -J /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/target/generated-sources/r -M /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/res --auto-add-overlay -A /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/assets -I /Users/myName/Desktop/sdk/platforms/android-10/android.jar, Result = 1
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.CommandExecutor$Factory$DefaultCommandExecutor.executeCommand(CommandExecutor.java:246)
        at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.phase01generatesources.GenerateSourcesMojo.generateR(GenerateSourcesMojo.java:480)
        ... 22 more
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 1.939s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Aug 21 17:30:10 CEST 2013
    [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/207M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.6.0:generate-sources (default-generate-sources) on project RecipeAndroid: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = /bin/sh -c cd /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid && /Users/myName/Desktop/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/aapt package -m -J /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/target/generated-sources/r -M /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/res --auto-add-overlay -A /Users/myName/Documents/projectName/project-android/RecipeAndroid/assets -I /Users/myName/Desktop/sdk/platforms/android-10/android.jar, Result = 1 -> [Help 1]
```

The project is pretty huge, so most likely I missed something in pom.xml, but I don't know what. Here is my pom.xml :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.asd.android.dsa</groupId>
    <artifactId>asd</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>asd - App</name>

    <properties>
        <environment>development</environment>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
            <version>r7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>20030203.000550</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>12.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-no_aop</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.http-client</groupId>
            <artifactId>google-http-client-android</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.0-rc</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpmime</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.roboguice</groupId>
            <artifactId>roboguice</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oauth.signpost</groupId>
            <artifactId>signpost-commonshttp4</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.twitter4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>twitter4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.11</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sdk>
                        <path>${env.ANDROID_HOME}</path>
                        <platform>10</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <deleteConflictingFiles>true</deleteConflictingFiles>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error appears to give no proper lead to solution. The problem is above this error - I haven't pasted it because it was labeled by [INFO] which I thought is not important. It is. After resolving [INFO] issues, above error disappeared.